# 301 редирект через .htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, .htaccess

Здравствуйте. В настоящий момент при попытке открыть [https://сайт.ru](https://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru) идёт 301 редирект на [http://www.сайт.ru](http://www.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru) (без https). Пожалуйста, помогите скорректировать файл .htaccess таким образом, чтобы:

1) При обращении по адресу [http://сайт.ru](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru) открывался сайт [http://www.сайт.ru](http://www.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru)

2) При обращении по адресу [https://сайт.ru](https://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru) открывался сайт [https://www.сайт.ru](https://www.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru)

Текущий .htaccess выглядит следующим образом.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.сайт.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Даниил, всё работает. Вы мастер!